# Brachistochrone step from Advanced classical mechanics (Bagchi)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, lagrange-multiplier, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm not sure as to how the book got from:

$dx=\frac{a+b}{2}\int{\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}}\sin(\theta)d\theta}$

to:

$x=\frac{a+b}{2}(\theta-\sin(\theta))+constant$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

I have tried the substitution of $u=\cos\theta$ among other ones and integration by parts. Not sure what's meant to happen because my answers are way too complex and differ by more than a constant. Do you integrate twice?

Edit: I believe there might have been an error in the printing of the question. This seems to be what was intended:
$dx=\frac{a+b}{2}\int{\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}}\sin(\theta)d\theta}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply divisor and dividend with $\sqrt{1+\cos(\theta)}$:
$$
\int \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}}\sin(\theta)d\theta
= \int \frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\theta)}}\sin(\theta)d\theta
= \int (1+\cos(\theta)) d\theta
= \theta + \sin(\theta)
$$

There seems to be a sign error in the expression you have — or have I made a sign error that I cannot see right now?

Comment: It's because $\sqrt{\sin^2{(\theta)}}=\pm\sin{(\theta)}$, but the solution given by the OP is incorrect. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+sqrt%7B(1%2Bcos(x))%2F(1-cos(x))%7Dsin(x)

Comment: Your calculation is correct but it appears that what I have typed is also correct. What @PeterForeman said sounds correct but I'm not sure what step that comes in.

Comment: The answer is either one of $\pm(\theta+\sin{(\theta)})$ depending on the range of $\theta$. But it is not $\theta-\sin{(\theta)}$.

Comment: I believe the answer is correct as it is meant to be the parametric equation for a cycloid, however, there might be an issue with the first part in the book.

Comment: @PeterForeman Please check my edit of the question. I think that should give the correct answer.

Comment: @TNTCookie. Swapping the signs in numerator and denominator, as you have suggested in your edit, will result in $\theta - \sin(\theta)$. So probably there's a mistake in the book.

Comment: I have contacted the editor. Can I ask what happens to the dx after the integration? Is it possible that there is another error in that they didn't integrate both sides?

Comment: Yes, it seem like it should be
$$dx=\frac{a+b}{2} {\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}}\sin(\theta)d\theta}$$
and
$$x=\frac{a+b}{2}\int{\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}}\sin(\theta)d\theta} = \frac{a+b}{2}(\theta-\sin(\theta))+C$$